# N different versions of a single key that points to a json value with size M or N different keys with values of size M / N?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to ask which approach is better - to have N different versions of a single key that points to a json value with size M or to have N different keys with values of size M / N?

I`m using CouchDB as a state databse.

Example:

Single key with many versions(every value will be inserted after different chaincode invocation):

```
"singleKey:1" -> {"values":[v1]}
"singleKey:2" -> {"values":[v1, v2]}
"singleKey:3" -> {"values":[v1, v2, v3]}
...
"singleKey:m" -> {"values":[v1, v2, v3, ..., vm]}
```

Multiple keys with one version:

```
"key1:1" -> {"value":"v1"}
"key2:1" -> {"value":"v2"}
"key3:1" -> {"value":"v3"}
...
"keym:1" -> {"value":"vm"}
```

Are there some optimizations for persisting arrays in the ledger? For example to keep only the changes without copying everything.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understood your question correctly. But you have generally 2 approaches for doing this. But before going into the details, storing a single key with an array as a value with each version getting appended is a strict no-no.

This is because, when you modify the same key concurrently or in different transactions in the same block, you will surely end up with an MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error.

This is because Fabric uses Optimistic Locking for committing read/write sets.

Coming back to the approaches [Both approaches are StateDB agnostic, you can use Couch/goLevelDB]:

**Approach 1**:
If you need to use the version while fetching the value, store each key as a composite key

```
key1-ver1 -> val1
key1-ver2 -> val2
.. and so on
```

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L128
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L121

**Approach 2**:
If you do not need the version while fetching, just need to fetch the previous versions, then Fabric internally stores the history of modification of a key using its own mechanism. You can query this history using APIs of chaincodes.

https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetHistoryForKey
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L161

You can have a look at the marbles example for an idea of both approaches:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/chaincode/marbles02/go/marbles_chaincode.go